# Keydown event Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

I wrote a script that trigger a submit button when i press enter key in a textarea, the TextArea returns to the line before the submit is activated.

I want to obstruct the TextArea to not return to the line

there is my script

```
jQuery( "#div1" ).on( "keydown", function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13){ 
        if(document.getElementById('checkbox').checked){             
            jQuery("#envoyer").trigger('click');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cancel the event!

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Just make sure to only do that when you're submitting the form - it'd be very easy to accidentally nuke all ability to type in the textarea at all ;)

Also, as a usability hint, I would suggest adding `&& !event.ctrlKey && !event.shiftKey` to your `if` condition, as this allows people to enter line breaks manually as they would in many chat programs - if you explicitly don't want newlines, you may be better just using `<input type="text" />` instead of `<textarea>`, especially since this comes with built-in Enter-to-submit-form functionality.